# Documenting application

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

The best is the app which does not need any documentation. 
The second step from the ideal is the app with concise and clear tooltips. 
The same time tooltips are a must!...but..rules exist to be broken ;-) and the last often leads to  dire consequences. So it's the starting point.
We have rather large app without documentation. We refactor it slowly but user want some documentation now. We also have several technical writers who could document our software and they have some spare resources for it.
I have an idea how to ease their work.

User moves mouse to the control, activates (by a shortcut) DocTool and enters the description of the control. This description becomes a tooltip for the pointed control.
So all this feature is a component.

Q1: Anybody knows whether such component exists?

Q2: How can control be uniquely identified for later referencing? (automated UI testing tools somehow manage to do it)

Comment: Is DocTool something you already have or that is what you want?   I suspect you could extend all the base controls.   How would you do security so that not just anyone could activate DocTool?   It would ease the work of the technical writers but more moving parts means more work for the developers.

Comment: @BalamBalam  DocTool is what we want. We know who of the users has the writes to activate the tool. This 'more' is ok cause our app is used internally by many departments including technical writers, so users are close to us and we don't want to make them angry =)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**
You could check out [WPF Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx) and apply similar techniques to each control's ToolTip property.

**Option 2**
Create an editable external data source (e.g. XML file).  This data source should have at least an `Id` and `ToolTip` column.

Create a singleton which wraps your data source (e.g. `ToolTipData`) and exposes access to each row via the data source's `Id`.

Define an attached property for `FrameworkElement` of type `string` called `ToolTipId`.  Attach it to each control which needs a tooltip.  (Ensure a unique value is applied to each control.)  `ToolTipId` value should map to an `Id` value from the data source.

In the attached property callback, set the ToolTip like so using the `ToolTipId`:

```
frameworkElement.ToolTip = ToolTipData.Default.Tooltips[ToolTipId];
```

Comment: note that every situation is different (you might use CSV data or something retrievable over the web), but this is how i'd start tackling the problem

Comment: How can I map Id to control? Even in WPF it requires setting x:Uid for every control, not to mention WinForms. There should be another way to identify control on the form. May be I'd use some kind ofthe path constructed by the names of the controls in a visual tree (WPF or WinForms)

Comment: to map the `Id` to a control, you use the `ToolTipId` attached property (as stated in the answer). `Control` : `ToolTipId` : `DataSource.Id` : `ToolTip`. I'd recommend against the constructed path, because then in your Data Source, you could have an Id like: `"Window.Grid.ListBox.ListBoxItem.StackPanel.CheckBox"`, which seems quite unwieldy ;)

Comment: Well, attached properties are good. But they're ok only fo WPF. And as you said we have to set tooltipid property for every control that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: if you _need_ it for WinForms too, i usually put other data in a control's `Tag` property. however, you have to have some way to identify the target control, so one can either slap an id value on the necessary controls OR create a complex algorithm to determine the control OR ...? this can be a difficult question; please provide an alternate answer if you know of one.

Comment: I think (but haven't tryed yet) that the task is easier foк WinForms. Eeah control has a Name by default, so we can map control's path  to its description. We do not want numerous changes in the code like adding x:Uid or smth to the Tag property. So called DocTool should augment rather than 'intrude' existing code.